# How to send all clicked links to a page before going to the URL in the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, coldfusion, href

**Question: How would I set up a page so that all links when clicked go to a page called query_data.cfm where a database query is triggered and once complete send the user to the url of the original link?**

As of right now I am adding a class to all links on my page using javascript.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('a').addClass("tracker");
});
</script>
```

But what I also want to do is make it so all links with that class for example `<a class="tracker" href="www.mywebsite.com/page2.cfm">Page 2</a>` go to a page named www.mywebsite.com/query_data.cfm where a query is ran passing the value of `href` to a database and once complete redirect the user to `www.mywebsite.com/page2.cfm`

I hope this is enough information but if I missed anything please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to simply change the links like:

`<a class="tracker" href="www.mywebsite.com/query_data.cfm?destination=page2.cfm">Page 2</a>`

Then all links will go to `query_data.cfm` which will record the `#URL.destination#` information and then `CFLOCATION` them on to #URL.destination#.

Comment: would you be able to help me with the javascript that would update all the links on my page to covert them into the logic you have outlined above with a static url of query_data.cfm being the main url and the actual url being a _GET variable?

Comment: The [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abbottmw/gusbft5q/) that I created does replace the location.  If javascript is disabled though, it will act like regular links.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Oh, you are the same person, my bad. Reading malfunction.

I suggest that you try this: http://jsfiddle.net/xcr56gd1/.

Since you're using jquery to add to the links, you can hopefully see how you can use jquery to change the href to `/r.cfm?d= + $(this).attr('href'), properly encoding as a url.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("a").not(".norm").on("click", function(e) {
        alert($(this).attr('href'));
        // The alert just demonstrates that it's working and how to get href.
        // You can call your ajax here.
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

With this code, you can use the jquery on all links without the class "norm", so if you especially wanted a link not to track, this is how you would do it.

Comment: I was writing up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abbottmw/gusbft5q/) myself for this as a proof of concept.

Pretty much the same idea as yours.

Comment: Thank you cfqueryparam this will be very helpful just so I understand... Where you have the comment about the 'ajax here" would this be where I can add my database query code? OR does that still have to go into a separate file between this link and the url it is pointing to/

Comment: It would go into a seperate file, this is a very basic ajax posst though, all that you would need to post to it is the url of the link, the other data, like session stuff available to the ajax page called.